# Why do I get syntax error: identifier FHttpRequestPtr

Tags: c++, unreal-4, http

I'm trying to add HTTP requests to my game and everything compiles fine until I try to set up a delegate for when the response is ready. Adding this function causes the compiler to fail for syntax error identifier FHttpRequestPtr.

header

```
void OnSaveTokenResponse(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful);
```

cpp

```
void UGamejoltApi::OnSaveTokenResponse(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful)
{

}
```

I have both `#include "Http.h"` and `#include "Interfaces/IHttpRequest.h"`. I also have this in my build file `PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "HTTP" });`.

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated. I can't make the game without the ability to make some HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to move the `#import "Http.h"` to the header file. Then it compiles fine.